# Excel VBA copy paste picture besides each other

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA Excel code is a Nutrifacts calculator. It calculate the nutrifacts, every country has a different layout and computations. The Nutrifacts layout is in every different sheets. And I tried to make a combobox, and select which country the user to choose.

I want to try and add some more. I want to add a checkbox of different country and the selected country will show the nutrifacts. For example, I selected US, Japan and China. These three country nutrifacts will show besides each other. My problem here is the positioning of the picture(paste).

Please see this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Code:

```
 If Me.chkCountry.Value = "TAIWAN" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(10).Range("B5:I27").CopyPicture    Appearance:=xlScreen,        Format:=xlBitmap

        With Sheet10.Pictures.Paste
        .Left = Range("A1").Left ' <-- setting the left postion to Cell A1
        .Top = Range("A1").Top ' <-- setting the top postion to Cell A1
        End With

If Me.chkCountry.Value = "UNITED STATES" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(10).Range("C5:I26").CopyPicture    Appearance:=xlScreen,        Format:=xlBitmap

        With Sheet10.Pictures.Paste
        .Left = Range("A1").Left ' <-- setting the left postion to Cell A1
        .Top = Range("A1").Top ' <-- setting the top postion to Cell A1
        End With
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Maybe include pictures comparing what your code does and what you want it to do?  I'm afraid you won't get good answers with the question as it stands right now.  You might also want to review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some other tips on asking questions.

Comment: Okay wait I will update my question.

Comment: Is `A1` where you want the first, then in say `J1` the second country, and `K1` the third? Can you perhaps do a sample of the expected output?  Do you have the combobox yet, or are you also asking for help on that part?